# removing the double quotes from list of elements

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

i have a list and where my list is coming as some elements being as double quotes with no value inside it

like:

```
ID,"",name,"",email,date,description,"",timelogged
```

i am trying to get a list which has

```
ID,name,email,date,description,timelogged
```

i tried converting the listoarray and then back to list to remove empty list elements, but it is not doing so.

is there any regex i can use to do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfscript>
    list = 'ID,"",name,"",email,date,description,"",timelogged';
    aItems = listToArray(list);
    aItems = aItems.filter(function(value){
        return value != '""';
    });
    newList = arrayToList(aItems);

    writeOutput("Starting list: " & list & "<br />");
    writeOutput("Filtered list: " & newList & "<br />");
</cfscript>
```

Comment: No need to convert to an array, just use `ListFilter`: `newList = list.ListFilter( function( value ){ return value != '""';} )`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove all of the empty string elements, then just remove all of the empty string elements.

```
<cfset x = 'ID,"",name,"",email,date,description,"",timelogged'>

<cfset x = rereplace(x, "#chr(44)##chr(34)##chr(34)#", "", "all")>

<cfoutput>#x#</cfoutput>
```

Output

```
ID,name,email,date,description,timelogged
```

Comment: Low quality answer. This won't replace a leading double quote due to your comma requirement. There is also no need to have **re**Replace with this pattern. `'(^|,)"{2}(,|$)'` would have been the proper pattern, but that still leaves you without the proper comma filler.